# how make relationship between two table asp.core code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, code-first

i have two table , Person and Courses
this is table Person :

```
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public int Name { get; set; }
 public int CourseID1 { get; set; }
 public int CourseID2 { get; set; }
```

for table Courses :

```
 public int CourseID { get; set; }
 public int Name { get; set; }
```

every person have 2 courses.
i do know how i can make a relationship for them in asp.core code first

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement

> Every person have 2 courses

So I will design your entity like this. Person class will have ICollection Course. ICollection mean you have at least one or more relationship data with Course class (mean 1 person can have more than 1 course)

Person class

```cs
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Courses> Courses { get; set; }
```

And the Courses class will have to reference back to Person class. 1 course belong to one person

```cs
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get;set; }
```

Please let me know if you need any help

Comment: Don’t u think it’s better to lazy load the collection?

Comment: @ShivamSood if you think there is better solution just add you anwser so I can learn from you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int Course1CourseID { get; set; }
    public Course Course1 { get; set; }
    public int Course2CourseID { get; set; }
    public Course Course2 { get; set; }
```

Edit: he was asking "person have 2 courses" like this

id     name    Course1    Course2
1      john     php        asp
2      mike     c#         core

above model will give you that.